# ¿Se puede usar la opcion de Real-Time de Supabase en conjunto con GraphQL?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql, real-time, supabase

Estoy replicando la aplicacion de "Trello" y queria saber si se puede usar GraphQL en conjunto on Supabase, para que pueda detectar los cambios en real-time ?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Y qué has intentado?